# What verb should I use for someone who 'deal with' internal circuits very well?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

I couldn't find out what verb should I use when I want to say

He was good at dealing with machines, and also he could even ***'verb'*** television internal circuits by himself.

In my language, *'manipulate'* is the verb we use (when we literally translate it into English), but I'm not sure if it's an appropraite use in English as well,
so I also came up with *'work with'*, but I guess it's too broad and unclear.
Or how about *'design'*? can it also be an option?

To sum up, when someone 'manipualtes' the internal circuits by him/herself very well, what verb can be used? Is 'manipulate' also work in English as well? or what else can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Manipulate" means strictly means to "handle or control", but it often gives the idea of changing or altering something. He probably isn't changing the television circuits into something else. I assume he's just fixing them.

You could use "troubleshoot", which means to find the problem with something. That's likely what he'd be doing with television circuits.

I probably would not use the word `internal` there either. The circuits are only inside the television, so it's not needed, and it sounds odd.

> He could even troubleshoot television circuits by himself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I looked up the dictionary and from the definition of 'troubleshoot', it seems like this word is more focused on the problem 'solving', not just 'fixing' it. Can I still use this word when what I want to say is that he could 'fix' or 'deal with' circuits?

Comment: That's true, but that is also the most difficult part. Fixing it is easy once you know what the problem is. Finding the problem shows that you understand how it works.

Comment: Oh that's tricky..then can I just go for 'fixing' circuits? Is this sentence 'He could even fix television circuits by himself.' gramatically correct and natural?

Comment: Yes, that works too.